# Calling my_model.save() many times makes Django slow

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.7.

I am trying to do something like:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    for x in y:
        # Logic here.
        x.save()
```

This is very slow in Django 1.7. I expected better performance because I am in a `transaction.atomic` block. After some research I believe Django is hitting the database on every call to `save`, and using `autocommit`. <del>What are my options for speeding up this code? Ideally, I would not have to change the logic in the for-loop.</del> Is every call to `save` being run with `autocommit` on? Or does being inside the `transaction.atomic` block disable `autocommit`?

Comment: This is totally impossible to answer because you haven't provided any model code or any indication of what you're trying to do with model.save -- the best anyone can say is have you looked into [queryset.update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)?

Comment: Hitting the database is what save is for. Why are you calling it if you don't want to hit the db?

Comment: I updated the question. What I really want is to confirm that being inside the transaction.atomic block disabled autocommit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `save()` doesn't enforce `autocommit` on.  Your code inside the `atomic()` runs in the single transaction.